# Populating textbox with combobox selection using php javascript.

Tags: javascript, php

I have html form which populate data from database.
1st one is combo-box and 2nd one is text-box.

My questions is how do I get the text-box filled, by selecting combo-box.
I've already tried using javascript, but it didn't worked, please take a look at my code.

//this is the html form: when i choose nama_brg on combobox, it will search for harga in tb_baranga where nama = nama_brg

```
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width=100px>Nama Barang</td>';
    echo '<td>:</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo    '<select name="nama_brg" onchange="ambilharga()">
                <option value="kosong">PILIH</option>';

                $getbrg = "select * from tb_baranga";
                $query2 = mysql_query($getbrg);
                while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row2['nama'].'">'.$row2['nama'].'</option>';
                }
            echo '</select>';

    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

//this is my javascript

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

         function ambilharga()
         {
         <?php

         $cekbrg = "select * from tb_baranga";
         $hasil = mysql_query($cekbrg);
         while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
         {
           $namabrg = $row5['nama'];

           echo "if (document.add_invoice.nama_brg.value == '".$namabrg."')";
           echo "{";

           $gethrg = "select harga from tb_baranga where nama='".$namabrg."'";
           $hasil2 = mysql_query($gethrg);
           while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($hasil2))
           {
               $price = $data2['harga'];
               echo "document.getElementById('harga2').innerHTML = '".$price."' ";
                echo "document.getElementById('harga2').value = '".$price."' ";
           }


           echo "}";
         }

         ?>
         }
    </script>
```

and this is my table structure

```
tb_baranga
nama varchar 30
harga int
```

Comment: You need to call Ajax here. When you select the Combo value, Ajax request must be sent to server and collect the appropriate text. Then output the response value

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Follow the steps I mention below.

```
>> Check all values are coming proper in drop-down box.
>> Call jquery ajax on change of dd box. (Ref. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
>> Show the value you get in ajax to text-box.
```

Comment: could you correct my code?
i've already re-checked it but it seemed fine

Comment: Try it by your self my friend. You should change in function ambilharga() you define above.

Comment: Read updated answer. I give link. Accept answer as others will get help

Comment: thanks bro..one more question is query ajax's compability is good? does it support in all browser and php version 5 and older?

Comment: Yes It's compatible to all browsers.